# Why do I have to package my IntelliJ-project twice to get it exported?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, export, minecraft, redundancy

Currently I am working on a plugin for a minecraft-server. I use maven, so when I made a change and I want to test it out on my server, i double-click on 'package' on the right hand side. Then my Jar will be exported right into my pluginsfolder. BUT everytime I reload my server its still the previous version of the plugin not the version I wanted to expoert and test. However, if I export my plugin twice, it is the new version of the plugin. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does it work on the first try from the command line outside of IntelliJ?

Comment: Oh well, I have not tested this yet. Which command do I have to use?

Comment: Try `mvn package` - https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html#build-the-project Make sure that Maven is installed on your PC and added to the PATH

Comment: I actually fixed it.. I try to answer my own question now with my solution, even its a bit weird.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution. I had to organise my project
[image: project structure].

Now my project is getting exported every time I click on package.

Comment: I'm not saying the solution is wrong. I'm saying I don't know what the solution is! The answer doesn't tell me! Please make it so the answer says what the solution is.